# RewriteRule to remove all slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have tried everything and can't find a solution.
When a user access this URL

- http://www.mydomain.com/B/13/B0/BD62CB5382479EFE5EE122BE6FB.jpg?pid=5623

I want it to rewrite it to (not using redirect)

- http://www.mydomain.com/B13B0BD62CB5382479EFE5EE122BE6FB.jpg?pid=5623

how do I remove the '/' ?
Your help is very appreciated .

Comment: Thanks it worked 

Yes it will always have 3 slashes but I just included one query parameter there are 2 others qs= and d=


Here is a real call
http://www.mtdomain.com/B/13/B0/BD62CB5382479EFE5EE122BE6FB.jpg?pid=5623&qs=yvFwvef%26v%7dvlbr%2cdmzDx%7c%7d1%7cskbxzunetvxg1lst%27yzoFWvefYw%7bihn®%26Rojpdngo%29Wpuj%2cgnwDCjzwnv%27Czheuiz!Rggn%24Iz%25_r%7e2%27Gwup%29%28%3e%3a3%3f87%24Vsiku%29Sumnth%29Xvef%7f%24&d=www.sodastreamusa.com

When I pass in other query strings it stops working.
The loop example seemed like it went into an infinite loop  Do I need a [L] some where to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this rule (your htaccess must be located in your document root folder)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ /$1$2$3$4.jpg?pid=%1 [L]
```

EDIT: this code will only work with urls like in your example (with 3 slashes and `pid` in query string)

EDIT2: to simplify query string if you have multiple params (maybe in different order) we don't need `RewriteCond` anymore but `QSA` flag instead

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ /$1$2$3$4.jpg [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This will only remove the first 3 slashes. If there are more, those will stay.

Comment: I took the URL in the question as an example only. YOu MAY be right - I don't know, and I didn't want to cricicise your answer at all - but there may as well be an aribtrary number of slashes in different URLs that need to be removed, not only 3.

Comment: You're right. I answered regarding on OP's example. Let's see what it is about, maybe there are more slashes in his urls

Comment: I will always have 3 slashes thank you for this...
I have more query string (pid, qs & d)   how do I modify you example to include other query strings?

Comment: I added a rule for that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If that rule should remove any number of slashes, not just a fixed number, you have to create a loop. TO do so, you can use the [`\[N\]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n), which will cause the rewriting process to start all over with the current URL. Be careful when doing this, this could lead to infinite loops when done wrong ;)

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*) $1$2 [N]
```

Should work however. You can test it [with this online tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

[Edit]: Complete rewrite - I forgot about the `[N]` Flag ;)